# In Bash, how to test if there is a directory with the given path?

Tags: bash, dir

I have the following bash code:

```
drlist="/backups /Blogs /data /dpkg-repack /Scripts /var/www";
for word in $drlist; do
 echo $word;
done
```

What I need to do is test to see if the `$word` exists as a directory and if not do:

```
mkdir $word;
chown -R $user:users $word;
chmod -R 775 $word;
```

Then all dirs exist and are correctly set for my processing that follows.

Comment: Sorry could not get to the "code" mode from my phone!

Comment: FYI: Four leading spaces make the line formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

Latest code:

```
drlist="/backups /Blogs /data /dpkg-repack /Scripts /var/www";
for word in $drlist; do
    if [[ -d "$word" ]]; do
        echo "Found Dir=> $word";
    else
        echo "Creating Dir=> $word";
        mkdir -p $word;
        chown -R $user:users $word;
        chmod -R 775 $word;
    fi
done
```

Of course I really do not want to see any echos and could not resolve the negative for the dir test, so still need a little help with that.

On the current machine under test this ran correctly finding all but the "Blogs" dir which it correctly created!

Cheers!

OMR